# Vim syntax highlighting of inline markdown

Tags: vim, markdown

Is there any current vim plugin that allow me to highlight markdown text in a comment block of any arbitrary languages. And is that possible?

Comment: Can it be done without a plugin now?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168). It is based on [Different syntax highlighting within regions of a file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file), and provides a `:[range]SyntaxInclude markdown` command as well as functions to do so programmatically.

Comment: Great plugin! [Here a screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621995/vim-markdown-syntax-parser-on-indented-markdown-blocks) with the markdown use case in action (connected with a yet more crazy use case ;-)