# Let Vim interpret and highlight code comments/docs as markdown

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I came up with this idea/question yesterday. I think it's very cool to have bold fonts, external links, mathematical formulas and references when you are writing code comments/docs. Before posting this question I find this idea is not new, people have asked about it. According to what I have tried (including this one: [Mixing two syntax highlighting scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201896/mixing-two-syntax-highlighting-scripts)), there have been no working solutions (or detailed enough for it to work for people like me...).

I think this is not technically difficult, since syntax highlighters need to identify different syntax regions (comments, keywords, strings etc) before coloring them, just that we want the 'markdown' way to interpret the comment syntax region.

Are there any experienced Vim users that have done things similar, I would appreciate some hints or examples from you very much! (for example: how to interpret """docstring""" in python as markdown) Following is content of my ~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim file which does not work (I referred to this link: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_the_default_syntax_highlighting):

```
syn include @Pandoc syntax/pandoc.vim
"syn region pyDoc start="\"\"\"" end="\"\"\"" contains=@Pandoc
syn region pyDoc start=+\%(:\n\s*\)\@<=\z('''\|"""\)+ end=+\z1+ keepend
  \ contains=@Pandoc
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150989/vim-syntax-highlighting-of-inline-markdown

Comment: I saw that before, but felt using SyntaxRange plugin is an overkill, besides you need to modify the vimrc file for it to be automatic. I would prefer to modify just the python.vim syntax file.

Comment: If it's just for Python, that could work. But you need to understand the structure of the Python syntax file for that, and it may still break in corner cases. Integrating two existing syntaxes unfortunately isn't trivial.

Comment: @IngoKarkat That's bad news, I have spent about two hours trying that without success. Seems I have to live with dull comments for a while. What surprises me most is it seems not many people are interested in this (other questions similar to mine didn't receive much attention as well).